# Get hierarchical custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way how to get a tree structure of hierarchical custom taxonomies in WordPress?

Currently I'm using this code to show the taxonomies:

```
<?php

 $terms = get_terms( 'custom-category' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';

     }
     echo '</ul>';
 }


?>
```

But this code generates tags in following way:

```
<ul>
   <li>Tax1</li>
   <li>Tax2</li>
   <li>Tax3</li>
   <li>Tax4</li>
   <li>Tax5</li>
   <li>Tax6</li>
</ul>
```

The structure what I need is like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Tax1</li>
   <li>Tax2</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-panel 1">
        <div>Tax3</div>
        <div>Tax4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-panel 2">
        <div>Tax3</div>
        <div>Tax4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`wp_list_categories`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)